# PIVOT help needed

Tags: oracle

I have table and data like this in oracle

```
 create table ab (a varchar2(10), b  varchar2(10), c  varchar2(10) , d  number, e  number);
    insert into ab values ('yuxc', 'x13', 'shjsh', -1, 12345);
    insert into ab values ('yuxc', 'x15', 'shjsh', 12345, -1);
```

and I want data like this

```
 a         b1    b2    c            d          e
yuxc       x13   x15   shjsh        12345      12345
```

please help.

Comment: You'll have to explain bit more, what you undertand under the `-1`value.

Answer (score 0):

So far one posible solution matching your sample data.

If this is not an expected *general* solution you must provide more information

```
select 
   A, min(B) B1, max(B) B2, C, max(D) D, max(E) E    
from ab
group by A,C

A          B1         B2         C                   D          E
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
yuxc       x13        x15        shjsh           12345      12345
```